# svg animate not working when other one end

Tags: svg

```html
<svg id="background" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1366 635">
  <defs>
    <style>
      #mov-bg { fill: #800080; }
      #green-bg {fill: #008000;}
      #yellow-bg { fill:#ffd700 ; }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <polygon id="yellow-bg" points="0 0 172.77 0 1366 0 1366 635 0 635 0 0">
    <animate id="background3" begin="background2.end" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="1"
             to="0 0 170 44 302 462 1366 635 0 635 0 0"/>
  </polygon>
  <polygon id="green-bg"  points="0 0 172.77 0 1366 0 1366 635 0 635 0 0">
    <animate id="background2"  begin="background-animate.end" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="1"
             to="0 0 135.62 69.6 260.11 498.58 1366 635 0 635 0 0"/>
  </polygon>
  <polygon  id="mov-bg"  points="0 0 172.77 0 1366 0 1366 635 0 635 0 0">
    <animate id="background-animate"  begin="click" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="1"
             to="0 0 83.12 78.6 207.61 531.58 1366 635 0 635 0 0"/>
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

There are 3 backgrounds that should animate one by one.
When id="background-animate" ends I want id="background2" to start and so on
but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative sign is a special character in SMIL because its default meaning is the subtraction operator i.e. you can write id-1s. So if you have an id with a - sign you need to escape the - sign. Escaping is not implemented properly in some browsers, though it is in Firefox. So correcting that we get.

```html
<svg id="background" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1366 635">
  <defs>
    <style>
      #mov-bg { fill: #800080; }
      #green-bg {fill: #008000;}
      #yellow-bg { fill:#ffd700 ; }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <polygon id="yellow-bg" points="0 0 172.77 0 1366 0 1366 635 0 635 0 0">
    <animate id="background3" begin="background2.end" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="1"
             to="0 0 170 44 302 462 1366 635 0 635 0 0"/>
  </polygon>
  <polygon id="green-bg"  points="0 0 172.77 0 1366 0 1366 635 0 635 0 0">
    <animate id="background2"  begin="background\-animate.end" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="1"
             to="0 0 135.62 69.6 260.11 498.58 1366 635 0 635 0 0"/>
  </polygon>
  <polygon  id="mov-bg"  points="0 0 172.77 0 1366 0 1366 635 0 635 0 0">
    <animate id="background-animate"  begin="click" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="1"
             to="0 0 83.12 78.6 207.61 531.58 1366 635 0 635 0 0"/>
  </polygon>
</svg>
```